# Show subpages of a category in a custom menu

Tags: menus

I have added a post category to a custom menu through Admin.  But when it shows, it just shows the category name, and does not show the posts inside the category.  Is there a way to add an args; that the children post pages will also show with the category title in the menu?

This is my current function:

```
function wp_nav_links() {   
wp_nav_menu(
    array(      
        'menu' => 'nav_links',
        'theme_location' => 'nav_links', 
        'container_class' => 'nav-links clearfix', 
        'fallback_cb' => 'nav_links_fallback'
    )
);
}
```

Comment: `wp_nav_menu` accepts `'walker' => new My_Custom_Menu_Walker` argument, which is where you create a new instance of your walker class. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created a menu, you would have to drag in those pages, as the basic `Walker_Nav_Menu` class does not pull subchildren into it. If this is your desired effect, you could created a custom [Walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker), essentially duplicate the `start_el()` function of `Walker_Nav_Menu`, and perform a check on `$item->type` to see if you are dealing with a Category - then create your submenu manually.

Comment: sounds about right.  Not sure I understand all this yet.  Ill look into it. Thanks for now.

Comment: No problem - a `Walker` is essentially something you hand an array of `$items` (whether it be posts, menu objects, terms, etc.) and it spits out the listing structure in HTML. `start_el` (element) creates most of the `<li>` structure element, `start_lvl` creates the submenu `<ul>` tag, and 'end_lvl'/'end_el` close the tags. Hence why `start_el` is where all the action happens :)

Comment: from what I read I add 'walker' => new fn_walker() to my array, and add to functions file something like - class fn_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
      function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) etc?

Comment: Exactly! `start_el` is the real breadwinner as far as Walkers go - it's where the magic happens.